# Microsoft Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0, reportserver

We are currently using SQL Server 2008 R2 with Reporting Services. I have build a few reports with Report Builder 3.0 which work fine.

I would really like to know how or what the best approach is to adding an audio indicator. So we are able to sound an audio alert if a certain state is displaying?

What would the best way be to achieve this?

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. This service only produces roeports, charts, tables, etc. You will be able to do this through excel, vbscript, or some other type.